# Not able to debug VC++2019 64 bit application

Tags: visual-c++

Hi  I have a vc++ application, earlier it has target platform for 32 bit application, it was fine in all aspects (debugging, build, execution).
Now I want to port the same application to 64 bit target environment, which I  complied it without any issues, but NOT ABLE TO DEBUG the application, breakpoint never hit anywhere,  are there any settings( project/debug) specific to 64 bit target, which I need to modify,
And also I didn't find any information related to 64 bit debugging for VC++ application on internet.
Please someone help me with this!
thanks,
Palaksha

Comment: The question is too broad. No one can help you with that useless wall of text without any information. If the breakpoint doesn't hit then you're not loading the correct symbols or files. Go to `Debug > Windows > Modules` and check if the corresponding symbols were loaded

Comment: when I  Goto Debug>Windows>Modules  it is showing  cannot find or open the PDB file for so many dlls,  with version 10.19041.